# print second column in transposed row

Tags: text-processing

I have a space separated table (as in this example):

```
A 101
B 92 102
C 83 93 103
D 74 84 94 104
  ︙
```

I would like to obtain this:

- sample A with the associated value and all the second column (starting from the first value of sample B) transposed in a row
  (in other words, the entire first row, followed by the second field from every subsequent row),
- sample B with the associated values and all the second column (starting from the first value of sample C) transposed in a row
  (in other words, the entire second row, followed by the second field from every subsequent row),
- etc.

This is the first five columns of the first four rows of my output:

```
A 101 92 83 74 …
B 92 102 83 74 …
C 83 93 103 74 …
D 74 84 94 104 …
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
{
    a[NR]=$0
    b[NR]=$2
}
END{
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){
        k=i+1
        printf("%s ",a[i])
        for(j=k;j<=NR;j++)
            printf("%s ",b[j])
        print ""
    }
}' table.file
```

At first script builds two arrays (`a` and `b`) with `NR` (row number) as index. Than add to each element of array `a` all elements of array `b` but without first `k` ones.
For case of memory limitation the same can be done by double pass of input file:

```
awk '
NR==FNR{
    b[NR]=$2
    rows=NR
    next
}
{
    printf("%s ",$0)
    for(j=FNR+1;j<=rows;j++)
        printf("%s ",b[j])
    print ""
    }
}' table.file table.file
```

Comment: It works but i don't have blank line in my input file how can i fix the script?

Comment: @IlarioFerrocino Let me see example

Comment: my input file dose not have blank line as in the example

Comment: @IlarioFerrocino I didn't see any empty line in output